# I have upgrade to 1.9.3 and now i realized i have to apply SUPEE 8788 before upgrade. is there any way to apply patch now?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-8788, ce-1.9.3.0

I have upgrade to 1.9.3 and now i realized i have to apply SUPEE 8788 before upgrade. Is there any way to apply patch now?

I can't see any SUPEE 8788 patch for 1.9.3

Is it advisable to apply last version of patch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SUPEE-8788 is included in Magento 1.9.3.0** so you don't have to apply it before upgrading.

Comment: are you sure? I have read this from magento release note for 1.9.3

Comment: @Kul 100% sure !!

Comment: Important! Use Magento Community 1.9.3 or later for all new installations and upgrades to ensure that you have the latest fixes, features, and security updates. Also i have test my magento store on Magereport which show patch is not applied!

Comment: @Kul https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MTbU9Bq130zrrsJwLIB9d8qnGfYZnkm4jBlfNaBF19M/edit#gid=192164130

Comment: Ok Great so as per instruction here [link](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/magento-patch-supee-8788-release-1-9-3/) I have to remove .swf files from here skin/adminhtml/default/default/media?

Comment: @Kul if you copied the 1.9.3 files over the old files yes delete the SWF files ;)

Comment: @Kul feel free to mark your question as answered so other people can benefit from it